# Casperjs - not able to save cli options while running casper_script via node

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, casperjs, args

I am running casper script via node using child_process execFile function, passing some data cli params.. But when i run the script i couldn't able to store those cli opts into variable for using them..

```
var casper = require("casper").create();
casper.echo("Casper CLI passed options:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options);
// I want those all dumped data into single variable i.e.,  object but couldn't able to
// var options1 = require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options); 
// var options2 = casper.cli.options; 
casper.exit();
```

Here is the logs:

```
['Casper CLI passed opts:\n',
  '{\n    "page": 1,\n    "store": "Hello",\n    "title": "Flex App"\n}]
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I've found that i wasn't able to store those cli opts into variables or etc but can get the params values using `casper.cli.get(index)` and use as  much i want it to use it (within that script).. this solved my problem without storing into variables..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that i wasn't able to store those cli opts into variables but can get the params values using

`casper.cli.get(index)`

and use as much i want it to use it (within that script).. this solved my case without storing into variables..

Hope this may help others when they come over here.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

> I want those all dumped data into single variable

Usually, CLI options are name-value pairs like

```
casperjs your_script.js --cliOne=one --cliTwo=two ....
```

And more often than not, it makes sense to get them into individual variable, like so:

```
var cliOne = casper.cli.get('cliOne');
```

But if you want to store all of them into one variable, you can still use the `casper.cli.options`, which will be a string, and then use JSON.parse (since it's comma separated name-value pairs and can be modeled as a JSON string).